Azure Container Apps dynamic revision url
I'm working on Azure Container Apps (ACA) but facing a weird issue. Every time I make change in and deploy the image, I get a new revision with its own URL. However, application URL remains un-changed. Informing customers/users about new revision URL with every change is unacceptable. I'm sure MS has thought through this and have an answer for this. I'm unable to find it though. Any help is appreciated.
Details:
I'm using single-revision mode and sitting behind my custom vNet.
My app URL is dev-poc.sharkfield-027d79f1.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io which never loads in browser however my revision url is dev-poc---ngnm1ss.sharkfield-027d79f1.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io which always loads in browser. But this revision url keeps changing.

revision url always changes when you create a new deployment. did you investigate why your app url not working ? Tho you can customize the revision url (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions#customize-revisions), i would highly recommend investgate why your app url not working properly

Any pointers on investigating why the app url is not working properly but the revisions url is? Thanks

The new revision-specific URL you are seeing (dev-poc---ngnm1ss.sharkfield-027d79f1.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io) is tied to the new image revisions and is primarily for internal purpose. Your customers/users should not access that. Instead customer/user should be able to access the app using the consistent primary app URL (i.e. dev-poc.sharkfield-027d79f1.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io) No need to share with them your revision URLs.
FYI- In container apps when you deploy a new image, a new revision is created, which results in a new URL for that revision.
You are already using single-revision mode, which should automatically route users to the latest revision using the primary app URL.
However, since the primary app URL is not loading, this likely related to the network configuration or firewall rules. Check for any misconfiguration in your VNet/firewall or NSG that could be blocking traffic to the primary URL. Check if there is any restriction blocking traffic to the primary URL (dev-poc.sharkfield-027d79f1.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io)



References:

Update and deploy changes in Azure Container Apps
Manage revisions in Azure Container Apps
Troubleshoot a container app

